# How to use html-minifier npm module?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to minify my html files from node.js using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier

I have this code

```
                // minify the html code
                fse.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);
                    var result = minify(data.toString(), {
                        removeAttributeQuotes: false
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                });
```

However it logs the same code as from the original file. It didn't minify it. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of the html-minifier options are disabled by default.

Try with some [options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference):

```
{
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  removeComments: true,
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
}
```